# How to set Expression attribute names in @Query annotation for spring data DynamoDb

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query my DynamoDB for a field status based on my Hash key and IndexRangeKey. I specified the field name which is required 'status' but i get exception for Reserved keyword.

Exception is

```
nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: status
```

I tried using DynamoDBMapper but that is a long code to write on and i want to implement it in a repository way

```
@Query(fields = "status")
    fun findAllByTargetMasterIDEqualsAndEndDateIsGreaterThanEqual(targetMasterID: String, endDate: Date = Calendar.getInstance().time) : MutableList<OffersRegistry>
```

I want to specify aliasing for status field in query annotation